# Merge the rows with least abundance

Tags: r, merge

I would like to merge rows lower than specific value, like:

```
ID  A   B   C
Apple   1   1   1
Banana  2   2   2
Cherry  3   3   3
Dates   4   4   4
```

For Apple, the total amount in A, B and C is 3, which is 10% (3/30*100%=10%) in total.

I would like to merge the rows with amount lower than 20% in total into a "Others" row, like:

```
ID  A   B   C
Cherry  3   3   3
Dates   4   4   4
Others  3   3   3
```

May I know how to draw the function and how to achieve this?

Any suggestion or idea is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do it like this:

```
## Your original data
df <- read.table(text="ID  A   B   C
Apple   1   1   1
Banana  2   2   2
Cherry  3   3   3
Dates   4   4   4" ,stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

names(df) <- df[1,] ## adding column names
df <- df[-1,]  ## removing the header row

df[,-1] <- lapply(df[,-1], as.numeric)  ## converting to numeric

rownames(df) <- df[,1]  ## adding rownames
df <- df[,-1]  ## removing the header column

df$tots <- apply(df, 1, sum)
df$proportion <- df$tots/sum(df$tots)
df <- rbind(df[which(df$proportion >= 0.2), ], 
            Others=apply(df[which(df$proportion < 0.2), ], 2, sum))
df <- subset(df, select = -c(tots, proportion))
```

The result:

```
>df
>Banana 2 2 2
>Cherry 3 3 3
>Dates  4 4 4
>Others 1 1 1
```

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to create a logical index by dividing the `rowSums` of numeric columns with the total `sum` to check if it is less than or equal to 0.2, then assign the 'ID' based on the index to "Others" (assuming that the "ID" column is `character` class) and `aggregate` the columns by 'ID' to get the `sum`

```
i1 <- rowSums(df1[-1])/sum(as.matrix(df1[-1])) <= 0.2
df1$ID[i1] <- "Others"
aggregate(.~ ID, df1, sum)
#      ID A B C
#1 Cherry 3 3 3
#2  Dates 4 4 4
#3 Others 3 3 3
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I tried but I got:

Warning message:
In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, i1, value = c(NA, NA, 3L, 4L)) :
  invalid factor level, NA generated

may I know why?

Comment: @LennonLee  As \i mentioned in the comments, i assumed that the 'IS' column is `character`.  \here, it looks like it is `factor`.  So, you can convert to `character` first `df1$ID <- as.character(df1$ID)` and then it should work or create `Others` as one of the levels in the `factor` column `levels(df$ID) <- c(levels(df$ID, "Others")` (if you wish not to change the clas